# Screen turns off after lock session

Tags: screen, lock

Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME

When I lock my computer  screen turns off for a shot period. How to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution for these problem.

**Option One**

Try replacing the default screensaver with another one, like xscreensaver.

**Option Two**

When you manually lock your screen, just hold the buttons a second longer and the screen won't turn off.

Source Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110833/10711557